# Leaflet latLngToContainerPoint and containerPointToLatLng not reciprocal?

Tags: leaflet

Anybody know why the following is not reciprocal? latLng and new

```
  var point = dispmap.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng);
  var newPoint = L.point([point.x, point.y]);
  var newLatLng = dispmap.containerPointToLatLng(newPoint);
```

When I execute this code I send in latlng=(26.75529,-80.93581)

newLatLng, which by inspection of the code above I would expect to reciprocate gives back...

newLatLng = (26.75542,-80.93628)

I'm wanting to array some markers with identical lat-lons around the shared spot on a map, and bumping each by some screen coordinates looks like the best method based on some blog/issue reading I've done.

I'm, "close" to what I want to achieve, but as I try to validate what these leaflet calls are doing for me I hit the fundamental question above.

Answer (score 0):

They can't be ...

Latitude and longitude are float values while x and y are integer values.

This means that there are an (theoretically) infinite number of latlng's and a rather small number of points on your view (width * height).

Furthermore, I'm not sure how you define identical latlng's; the best you can't to is to speak of proximity.

If I read between the lines, identical may mean that the markers overlap. Then the best way is to have a look how [Leaflet.MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) are tackling with the problem.

Comment: My intent is not to cluster locations that are in close proximity, but neatly array say 6 identical-location markers around their actual lat/lng. I THINK I should not perform a LatLng conversion to point and back again to LatLng, but instead just bump the icons by some pixel points.  The above conversion method was what I found reference too as I looked at the API. I'd seen the impressive cluster effort but it looks like more than I need, and as it clusters differing lat-lngs it won;t "separate" my markers at the highest zoom level, near as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for you advice...just wondering if you have a better recommendation, given my intent.

Comment: There is a spiderfyOnMaxZoom options that you can explore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my desired result by altering zoom level to avoid pixel-point quantization effects on my translations. The screenshot below illustrates an orange and two green circle markers that represent an identical lat-lon, but I want the green arrayed around the orange in a circular fashion...in this example there are only 2 green.

I perform simple circular array math with an angular step size of PI/4 in this example. The KEY to getting the visual effect correct is the "dispmap.setZoom(dispmap._layersMaxZoom)" call BEFORE I do the math,  and then I invoke "dispmap.setZoom(mats.zoom)" after the math, which will give the user the desired zoom level as specified by variable mats.zoom.

```
    var arrayRad=20;
    var dtheta=Math.PI/4;
    var theta=0;

    dispmap.setZoom(dispmap._layersMaxZoom)
    L.geoJson(JSON.parse(mats.intendeds), {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var point = dispmap.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng);
            dx = arrayRad*Math.cos(theta);
            dy = arrayRad*Math.sin(theta);
            theta += dtheta;
            var newPoint = L.point([point.x + dx, point.y+ dy]);
            var newLatLng = dispmap.containerPointToLatLng(newPoint);

            return L.circleMarker(newLatLng, intendedDeliveryLocationMarkerOptions);
        }, onEachFeature: onEachIntendedLocFeature }).addTo(dispmap);

    dispmap.setZoom(mats.zoom);
```

[Sample screen shot at max zoom level: 2 arrayed markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFfwj.png)